# Cannot set invisible property on button with url widget in Odoo10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to set up an attribute 'invisible' on button if the link is not given. But it returns me an error:

```py
Uncaught Error: Unknown field link in domain [["link","=",false]]
```

I guess, the problem is because the field I am trying to refer to has widget "url".

The form view where the field 'link' is set.

```xml
<record id="documents_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="model">documents.example</field>
    ...
        <field name="link" widget="url" placeholder="e.g. www.example.com"/>
    ...
</record>
```

The tree view where it happens:

```xml
<record id="documents_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="model">documents.example</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Documents">
            ...
            <button name="open_link" type="object" attrs="{'invisible': [('link', '=', False)]}"/>
            ...
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

The class itself:

```py
class Documents(models.Model):
    ...
    _name = 'documents.example'
    link = fields.Char("Link")
    ...

    def open_link(self):
        return {
            'name':         'Go to website',
            'res_model':    'ir.actions.act_url',
            'type':         'ir.actions.act_url',
            'target':       'new',
            'url':          self.link
        }
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are not including the `link` field in your tree view. Add the `link` field to your tree view and make it invisible.

```
<field name="link" invisible="1"/>
```